# I'm having trouble relating these two methods together

Tags: java

I'm creating a bank account program and I am making it so that the balance is always in U.S. dollars, but the problem is I don't exactly know how to mesh these methods together. Here's a little bit of my code. What I'm trying to ask is how does the converter method get the values used in my switch statement? I've tried multiple different ways , but I always have scope issues or duplicate variables.

```
public static double convertCurrency(double amount, int currencyType, boolean isConvertToUSD){
    //  checks what type of currency was chosen and converts each it into US dollars

    }
}

public static int currencyMenuOptionSelector(Scanner console){
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Please select the currency type:");
        System.out.println("1. U.S. Dollars");
        System.out.println("2. Euros");
        System.out.println("3. British Pounds");
        System.out.println("4. Indian Rupees");
        System.out.println("5. Australian Dollars");
        System.out.println("6. Canadian Dollars");
        System.out.println("7. Singapore Dollars");
        System.out.println("8. Swiss Francs");
        System.out.println("9. Malaysian Ringgits");
        System.out.println("10. Japanese Yen");
        System.out.println("11. Chinese Yuan Renminbi");
        int currencyType = console.nextInt();

        switch (currencyType){
        // cases 1-11 simply establishes each currency as a variable (not all cases are listed to avoid redundancy)
        case 1: {
            double USA = 1.00;
        }
        case 2: {
            double Euro = 0.89;

default: {
            System.out.println("Input failed validation. Please try again.");
            continue;
         }
        }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you call the converter method ? Also after each case there should be a `break;` to prevent falltrough

Comment: I'd like to call the converter method in an deposit method and a withdrawal method (these are not in my code posted).

Comment: The variables are declared in the switch statement, it's my guess that it is because of this reason that you are getting scoping issues. The moment the switch statement closes these variables are not accessible by any other code. Declare the variable as global and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should move the switch to the other method since that is where the calculation occurs.

You seem to be on the right path, but need to prompt for the amount to convert.

```
System.out.print("Enter the type of currency: ");
int currencyType = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());

System.out.print("Enter currency amount: ");
double amount = Double.parseDouble(console.nextLine());

if (currencyType < 1 || currencyType > 11) {
    // TODO: Handle invalid input.
}

boolean toUSD = currencyType == 1;
double convertedAmount = convertCurrency(amount, currencyType, toUSD);
```

And you need `break;` inside your cases.

Comment: This would be perfect, but im required to have my methods structured similar to the way I have them above. And when I move my switch statement to the other method my validation gets messed up. I tried calling the currencyMenuOptionSelector(console) method in the default case , but I get the error message "console cant be resolved into a variable." Is there something I'm missing/doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need curly braces on the `default` block. The `default` is just another `case` statement

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.You can try it and tell me if it meets your requirement.
And the

> scope issues or duplicate variables.

you meet may because you dont't write return statement or "break" if any switch case match.

```
public class ConverTest {

public static double convertCurrency(double amount, int currencyType, boolean isConvertToUSD){
    //  checks what type of currency was chosen and converts each it into US dollars

    System.out.println("the input type:" + currencyType); //you say you want to get the values used in my switch
    // statement.
    return 0.01; //i don't know what u want to do in this meshod.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    convertCurrency(100.0, currencyMenuOptionSelector(in), true);
}

public static int currencyMenuOptionSelector(Scanner console) {

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please select the currency type:");
        System.out.println("1. U.S. Dollars");
        System.out.println("2. Euros");
        System.out.println("3. British Pounds");
        System.out.println("4. Indian Rupees");
        System.out.println("5. Australian Dollars");
        System.out.println("6. Canadian Dollars");
        System.out.println("7. Singapore Dollars");
        System.out.println("8. Swiss Francs");
        System.out.println("9. Malaysian Ringgits");
        System.out.println("10. Japanese Yen");
        System.out.println("11. Chinese Yuan Renminbi");
        int currencyType = console.nextInt();
        switch (currencyType) {
        // cases 1-11 simply establishes each currency as a variable (not all cases are listed to avoid redundancy)
        case 1: {
            double USA = 1.00;
            return currencyType;
        }
        case 2: {
            double Euro = 0.89;
            return currencyType;
        }

            default: {
                System.out.println("Input failed validation. Please try again.");
                continue;
            }
        }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what I wanted it to do your code returns the user inputted choice number. My intention was to grab the currency selected by the user and then convert that currency into US dollars. In what way could I use the variables USA or Euro in the conversion method that I wrote out? Sorry if my question isn't very clear I might make another post with more information on my project.